# How to build OpenSSL 1.0.2 for Android 6.0.1?

Tags: android, c, ssl, openssl

I am working on an application which uses the OpenSSL library. I am trying to run the app on Android emulator without replacing the OpenSSL by boringssl. So I downloaded the AOSP source tree and I am currently able to lunch emulator.

To add OpenSSL, I git clone the `openssl` into `external/openssl`.

Based on the openssl project http://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android
I added different Android.mk files in the external/openssl, external/openssl/apps, external/openssl/crypto and external/openssl/ssl folder, added android-config.mk, and Application.mk to external/openssl folder. But when I run mm, the compiler spits an error:

```
build/core/base_rules.mk:217: *** external/openssl/crypto: MODULE.TARGET.SHARED_LIBRARIES.libcrypto already defined by external/boringssl.
build/core/ninja.mk:155: recipe for target 'out/build-aosp_arm-mmm-external_openssl_Android.mk.ninja' failed
make: *** [out/build-aosp_arm-mmm-external_openssl_Android.mk.ninja] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/rong/projects/Android/src'
```

Any one knows how to build OpenSSL in AOSP?

---

AOSP environment:

- PLATFORM_VERSION := 6.0.1
- PLATFORM_SDK_VERSION := 23
- PLATFORM_JACK_MIN_SDK_VERSION := 24

Development environment:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- GCC 5.4

Comment: As BoringSSL is also using same lib names, so you have to change the names of libcrypto.so and libssl.so. For generating these step by step, please follow my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these instructions may help :)

1. Download Android NDK (version ndk-r13b) from this url:

   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r13b-linux-x86_64.zip
2. Extract NDK to /home/Android.
3. Download the cross compilation setup script from this URL:

   https://wiki.openssl.org/images/7/70/Setenv-android.sh
4. Make following changes in the Setenv-android.sh script:

   a: Add the following line to the start of the script:

   ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/Android/android-ndk-r13b

   b: Modify _ANDROID_NDK="android-ndk-r13".

   c: Modify _ANDROID_EABI="arm-linux-androideabi-4.9"

   d: Modify _ANDROID_API="android-23"
5. Download the openssl (version 1.0.2n) from this url:

   https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.2/openssl-1.0.2n.tar.gz
6. Extract the downloaded tarball.
7. Open new terminal window and navigate to extracted directory.
8. Move the Setenv-android.sh script to this directory and execute the following commands:

   ```
   chmod a+x Setenv-android.sh
   source ./Setenv-android.sh
   ```
9. Run the following command (to configure OpenSSL sources to build for Android):

   ```
   ./Configure shared android
   ```
10. Execute following command to build libcrypto and libssl shared libraries.

    ```
    make CALC_VERSIONS="SHLIB_COMPAT=; SHLIB_SOVER=" build_libs
    ```
11. Let the build complete successfully.